# Left and Right Click in Minecraft not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I have a problem in Minecraft. I can't left or right click in the GUI(The Inventory or the crafting table). The weird thing though is that I can click crafting recipes and villager trades. While I can't then drag them into my Inventory. I always have to use my numbers to move them to my hot-bar. This is really annoying because then I always have to drop some items out of my hot-bar.
Does anybody have the same problem or the answer.

PS: I created a second user on my Mac and there minecraft is working. But to switch users all the time is very annoying.

If you want I can post a video too. Just ask me to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: do you have any other programs or applications open that have an overlay of sorts? i know that Medal, a clip recording software, had a problem in some games where its recording overlay oddly interrupted click-drag.