# Minecraft click-drag not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I have a very weird problem in Minecraft. My click-drag is not working. I can punch and place blocks in-game but when it comes to crafting I try to click the block and then drag it into the crafting grid but it won't recognize my click. I also tried shift clicking on an item but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Can you show a quick screen recording of what you are encountering? This seems a bit like touchscreen mode turned on.

Comment: Do you mean a screen recording of my gameplay, or a screenshot of my settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left and Right Click in Minecraft not working](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/395686/left-and-right-click-in-minecraft-not-working)

Comment: Do you mean drag clicking? I'm not sure what click-drag means.

Comment: Both a screen recording of your gameplay and a screenshot of your settings would be very helpful